# Calculate sum of maximum and minimum value for repeated group of entries in MySQL8

Tags: sum, max, window-functions, min, mysql-8.0

| LogDateAndTime | BatchDate | TagLetter | Totaliser | ExpectedResult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-11-2020 09:06:14 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A | 6319 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:06:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A | 6337 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:08:14 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B | 6355 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:08:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B | 6372 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:08:34 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B | 6378 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:08:44 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A | 6383 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:09:14 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A | 6388 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:09:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A | 6396 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:09:34 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B | 6409 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:09:44 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B | 6426 | 31 |
| 10-11-2020 09:10:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B | 6442 | 31 |

The above table has **LogDateAndTime(Primary_Key)** column with unique datetime entries. The **BatchDate** column holds same datetime values throughout the entire batch. I need to calculate the sum of MAX(Totaliser)-MIN(Totaliser) for each instance of TagLetter=A so that i should ignore values in TagLetter=B. My ExpectedResult in this case will be SUM[(6337-6319)+(6396-6383)]=**31**. I tried below query, but did not get the expected result.

```
SELECT SUM(
           CASE 
             WHEN TagLetter='A' THEN MAX(Totaliser)-MIN(Totaliser) 
             ELSE 0.0 
           END
          ) OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDate) AS ExpectedResult
```

In this case, it is calculating 6396-6319=**77** which is not the expected result. Could someone help me to get the result right?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy MySQL 8.0.22

Comment: don't you want to partition over `LogDateAndTime`?  The batch dates are all the same so I would expect the end result to be 77

Comment: Actually I see all the dates are different in LogDateAndTime.  Could you explain how you are expecting the results to be partitioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the groups of consecutive `'A'`s with window functions `LAG()` and `SUM()` and then aggregate on these groups:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT SUM(MAX(Totaliser) - MIN(Totaliser)) OVER () ExpectedResult
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY LogDateAndTime) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT *, LAG(TagLetter, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY LogDateAndTime) <> 'A' flag
      FROM tablename 
    ) t
    WHERE TagLetter = 'A'
  ) t
  GROUP BY grp
)
SELECT t.*, c.ExpectedResult
FROM tablename t CROSS JOIN cte c
```

Or if you want results for each `BatchDate`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT BatchDate,
         SUM(MAX(Totaliser) - MIN(Totaliser)) OVER () ExpectedResult
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDate ORDER BY LogDateAndTime) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT *, LAG(TagLetter, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDate ORDER BY LogDateAndTime) <> 'A' flag
      FROM tablename 
    ) t
    WHERE TagLetter = 'A'
  ) t
  GROUP BY BatchDate, grp
)
SELECT t.*, c.ExpectedResult
FROM tablename t LEFT JOIN cte c
ON c.BatchDate = t.BatchDate
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4802444fddacf873dac73b4ee76746ff).
Results:

```
> LogDateAndTime      | BatchDate           | TagLetter | Totaliser | ExpectedResult
> :------------------ | :------------------ | :-------- | --------: | -------------:
> 10-11-2020 09:06:14 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A         |      6319 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:06:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A         |      6337 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:08:14 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B         |      6355 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:08:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B         |      6372 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:08:34 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B         |      6378 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:08:44 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A         |      6383 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:09:14 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A         |      6388 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:09:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | A         |      6396 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:09:34 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B         |      6409 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:09:44 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B         |      6426 |             31
> 10-11-2020 09:10:24 | 10-11-2020 08:29:55 | B         |      6442 |             31
```

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. Could you possibly return a single aggregated value for each row, that is to return 31 in each row?

Comment: Thank you for your help, forpas.

Comment: In this line of query, i would like to compare C along with A  `SELECT *, LAG(TagLetter, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDate ORDER BY LogDateAndTime) <> 'A' flag`  How would I compare both A and C?  `SELECT *, LAG(TagLetter, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDate ORDER BY LogDateAndTime) <> 'A' OR 'C' flag FROM tablename` is giving same result as in above query.

Comment: @Midhunraj If you want `LAG(TagLetter, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDate ORDER BY LogDateAndTime)` not to be equal to both 'A' and 'C' then use: `LAG(TagLetter, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDate ORDER BY LogDateAndTime) NOT IN ('A', 'C')`

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to do this calculation `BatchDate` wise below is the solution with older methods.

```
with cte as (
select 
test.*, 
@rn := (if (@rt =TagLetter, @rn, @rn+1)) rank_,
@rt :=TagLetter
from test , (select @rn := 1,  @rt := '') t
)

select t1.*,t2.ExpectedResult from test t1
left join (
select  distinct BatchDate, sum(CASE 
             WHEN TagLetter='A' THEN MAX(Totaliser)-MIN(Totaliser) 
             ELSE 0.0 
           END) over ()
           AS ExpectedResult
          
          from cte
          
group by BatchDate,TagLetter,rank_) t2 on t1.BatchDate=t2.BatchDate
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a6aaec77b041aaa234bc502f0e0c100)